# Bootstrap 4 dropdown menu не под кнопкой

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap, dropdown, navigationbar

Не могу понять как сделать вывод `dropdown-menu` не под кнопкой а под самим меню, чтобы ширина этого `dropdown-menu` была равна ширине основной строки 
дабы не происходило выхода 2-3 столбца `dropdown-menu` за экран как это можно наблюдать на примере ниже (лучше развернуть на весь экран)

для наглядности :

[image: меню- описание]

```js
$('nav').on('mouseenter mouseleave','.dropdown',function(e){
  var _d=$(e.target).closest('.dropdown');_d.addClass('show');
  setTimeout(function(){
    _d[_d.is(':hover')?'addClass':'removeClass']('show');
  },300);
});
```

```css
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;

}
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar .navbar-text {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  margin: 0 0.25em;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:not(.disabled):hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:not(.disabled):focus {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border-color: #ffa500;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus,
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffa500;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-divider {
  border-top-color: #ffa500;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link:focus,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link:focus {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffa500;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ffa500;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ffa500;
}
.navbar .navbar-toggle .navbar-toggler-icon {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse,
.navbar .navbar-form {
  border-color: #000000;
}
.navbar .navbar-link {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

.dropdown-menu{
 column-count: 3;
 position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
 display: block;
}



@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffa500;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffa500;
  }

}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffa500;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffa500;
  }
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
  color: #000000;
}
.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffa500;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  sticky-top">

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">



          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">1234</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>


          <li class="nav-item dropdown  ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
          </li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown  mx-auto">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
          </li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown  mx-auto">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
          </li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown  mx-auto">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
          </li>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown  mx-auto">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
          </li>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown  mx-auto">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
          </li>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown  mx-auto">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
          </li>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown  mx-auto">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
          </li>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown  mx-auto">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
          </li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">1234</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить в CSS:

```
.sticky-top ul {
  position: relative;
}

.sticky-top ul>li {
  position: static;
}

.sticky-top ul>li .dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;    
}
```

```js
$('nav').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.dropdown', function(e) {
  var _d = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown');
  _d.addClass('show');
  setTimeout(function() {
    _d[_d.is(':hover') ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('show');
  }, 300);
});
```

```css
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #000000;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #000000;
}

.navbar .navbar-text {
  color: #000000;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  margin: 0 0.25em;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:not(.disabled):hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:not(.disabled):focus {
  color: #000000;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border-color: #ffa500;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  color: #000000;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus,
.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffa500;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-divider {
  border-top-color: #ffa500;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link:focus,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item.show .nav-link:focus {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffa500;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ffa500;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ffa500;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle .navbar-toggler-icon {
  color: #000000;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse,
.navbar .navbar-form {
  border-color: #000000;
}

.navbar .navbar-link {
  color: #000000;
}

.navbar .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  column-count: 3;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffa500;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffa500;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffa500;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffa500;
  }
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  color: #000000;
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:focus {
  color: #000000;
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffa500;
}

/*Добавить*/
.sticky-top ul {
  position: relative;
}

.sticky-top ul>li {
  position: static;
}

.sticky-top ul>li .dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
  top: 60px;/*Добавил чтобы не слитало появление dropbox
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  sticky-top">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">



      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">1234</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>


      <li class="nav-item dropdown  ">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown  mx-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown  mx-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown  mx-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown  mx-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown  mx-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown  mx-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown  mx-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown  mx-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">1234</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```